# slf4j not logging in DEBUG.log with log.debug(...)

Tags: java, spring, slf4j

I have problem with slf4j, logging at info and warning level works. But logging at debug level doesn't. I checked under debugger and log.isDebugEnabled() is true, so log.debug("INPUT:\n" + input) is executing but DEBUG.log is empty. I enabled in my IntelliJ IDE option "Enable debug output" (it adds VM option -Ddebug) and it still doen't work.

```
(..)
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
(..)
public class LoginController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    public AuthUser login(InputStream inputStream, HttpServletRequest    request) throws Exception {

      final String input = misc.InputStreamToString(inputStream);
      if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("INPUT:\n" + input);
     }

     (..)
   }
```

**Update 1:**

file resources/logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<property name="HOME" value="${user.dir}/logs"/>

<appender name="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>

    <file>${HOME}/DEBUG.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE-INSERT-INFO"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${HOME}/INFO.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${HOME}/archived/INFO.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE-INSERT-WARN"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${HOME}/WARN.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${HOME}/archived/WARN.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE-INSERT-ERROR"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <file>${HOME}/ERROR.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${HOME}/archived/ERROR.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <!--<appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG" />-->
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-ERROR"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What is your logging configuration ?

Comment: @Arnaud I added.

Comment: Your `"FILE-INSERT-DEBUG"` appender-ref is commented out in the XML.

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks, I commented out and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in commeted line in resources/logback.xml

```
<!--<appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG" />-->
```

After commented out it works:

```
</appender>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-WARN"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-ERROR"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -1):

You configure log level in configuration file, like this
*resources/slf4j.xml*

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.base22" level="TRACE"/>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

P.S. More information [Logback Documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) "Automatic configuration with logback-test.xml or logback.xml"

Comment: I have resources/logback.xml and it seems to be enabled there:  <root level="DEBUG"> ....  I included hole file logback.xml to the questioan.